# React nextJS function references it self and pulls data without an import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I bought [this template](https://themeforest.net/item/pickbazar-react-graphql-ecommerce-template/25283305) and am trying to understand which page getLayout in this code"{getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}" goes to on initial load. I'm guessing it's a global variable somewhere, but I can't find it using the definitions. I'm trying to under [the next.js documentation,](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages) but I'm having issues. If anyone has a good tutorial for this I'll happily take it.

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
import '@/assets/css/main.css';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import { ModalProvider } from '@/components/ui/modal/modal.context';
import ManagedModal from '@/components/ui/modal/managed-modal';
import ManagedDrawer from '@/components/ui/drawer/managed-drawer';
import DefaultSeo from '@/components/seo/default-seo';
import { SearchProvider } from '@/components/ui/search/search.context';
import PrivateRoute from '@/lib/private-route';
import { CartProvider } from '@/store/quick-cart/cart.context';
import SocialLogin from '@/components/auth/social-login';
import { NextPageWithLayout } from '@/types';
import QueryProvider from '@/framework/client/query-provider';
import { getDirection } from '@/lib/constants';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout;
};

function CustomApp({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);
  const authenticationRequired = Component.authenticationRequired ?? false;
  const { locale } = useRouter();
  const dir = getDirection(locale);

  return (
    <div dir={dir}>
      <SessionProvider session={session}>
        <QueryProvider pageProps={pageProps}>
          <SearchProvider>
            <ModalProvider>
              <CartProvider>
                <>
                  <DefaultSeo />
                  {authenticationRequired ? (
                    <PrivateRoute>
                      {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
                    </PrivateRoute>
                  ) : (
                    getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
                  )}
                  <ManagedModal />
                  <ManagedDrawer />
                  <ToastContainer autoClose={2000} theme="colored" />
                  <SocialLogin />
                </>
              </CartProvider>
            </ModalProvider>
          </SearchProvider>
        </QueryProvider>
      </SessionProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default appWithTranslation(CustomApp);
```

Comment: The [getLayout](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts) property will be defined at the page level. Here's an [official example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/layout-component) of a layout component, which you can reference. The `_app.js` page is a client-side only wrapper over all pages. So it'll take in the page as a `Component` and that's where you can reference `Component.getLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can define a [*per* component layout](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts). In order to do so, when you are defining a component, you add a property named `getLayout`. Here's an example, for a better understanding.

```js
// ...
const Component: React.FC = () => <div>
  I have a custom layout
</div>

// Here we define a layout, let's imagine it's a component
// we have inside /layouts and we have previously imported it
Component.getLayout = (page: React.ReactElement) =>
  <LayoutComponent>{page}</LayoutComponent>
```

Now, when a page is rendered (note that in a Next JS app, all pages are rendered as a children of what is inside `_app.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}`) your code checks if the prop `getLayout` has been defined or not. Then, it is basically calling such function, if exists, otherwise it renders the base component.